# Why is Python re.search adding spaces to my string?

Tags: python, regex, search

I want Python to open a Unicode text file, read through each line, and then write the line to a new Unicode text file if the line does not contain any digits. So if the input is:

```
1
8:00:00 --> 8:00:01
Hello World!
```

It should output:

```
Hello World!
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
H e l l o  W o r l d !
```

I'm not sure why its adding in the spaces between each character. What am I missing? Here is the code I'm using:

```
import re

nFile = open("NewFile.txt", 'w')

with open("OriginalFile.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not (re.search("\d", line)):
            nFile.write(line)
```

Comment: Check the encoding of your file.

Comment: I did, the input file is saved as a Unicode text file.

Comment: Well, I'm doing a save as with Notepad as Unicode. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzPUlp5zIAYTSkUwdjBfY3paemM/edit?usp=sharing) is the input file.

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzPUlp5zIAYTWmJNRDVzaWtkUmM/edit?usp=sharing) is the output file I'm getting. Thank you for your help! If this is an encoding issue any suggestion on how to resolve it?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.3.3 on Windows 7.

Comment: Just a tip: you can use `with open("OriginalFile.txt", 'r') as f, open("NewFile.txt", 'w') as nFile:` to guard both files with `with` clause.

Comment: The file is UTF16-LE. Not sure myself how best to read it. Do you have any possibility to save it as UTF8?

Comment: Thank you for the tip m.wasowski. I tried saving the file as a plain text UTF8 in Word, but now when I run the script I'm definitely getting an encoding error: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode by 0x81 in position...: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a tough one, but this seems to work.

First off, as we've already discussed in the comments, it's an encoding problem. In fact, `search` *could not* add spaces to the string even if it wanted to, because strings are immutable, so the only way to change `line` is by doing something like `line = ...`.

The input file you linked in the comments in encoded as `UTF-16-LE`, which is not the default format used by Python. One way to read it (there might be others, feel free to comment) is to use the [`codecs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) module.

```
import re, codecs
with codecs.open("HarryPotterSubsEs2.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-16-le") as f:
    for line in f:
        if not (re.search("\d", line)):
            print line
```

For writing the selected lines to the output file, you can do the same with the outfile, or do `line = line.encode("utf8")` to write the line to the file as `utf8`. (For some reason, the same did not work for reading the lines, there it caused a unicode error. Not 100% sure the encoding from UTF16 to UTF8 is lossless in this case; again, feel free to comment.)

As an alternative, you might find a way to save the file in a different encoding (preferrably `utf8` using a different text editor than Notepad...