# "Tabulate" function in python adding spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get my file into a table using the tabulate function of python however it's creating unnecessary gaps:

> [   '   E   w   a   n   '   ,   '   S   m   i   t   h   '   ,    1   0  ,    2  ,    5  ]   [   '   J   o   h   n   '   ,   '   S   m   i   t   s   '   ,    2  ,    6  ,    7  ]   [   '   A   m   y   '   ,   '   G   i   n   '   ,    2  ,    3  ,    6  ]   [   '   M   i   c   h   e   a   l   '   ,   '   J   o   n   e   s   '   ,    2  ,    3  ,        4  ].

I checked the file I got them from and there is no spaces.

```
from tabulate import tabulate 
scores=[]
studentscores=[]
class1=[]
class2=[]
class3=[]

classes=input("Hello, which class do you wish to open:")
if classes=='mathA':  
    with open('mathA.txt')as file:
       for line in file:
         scores.append(line.strip())
         classes=["b","C","A"]
         classes.sort()
print (tabulate(scores, headers=["Name","scores"],
            tablefmt="plain", numalign="right"))
```

Comment: My guess would be that the file is encoded as UTF-16 and you are reading it as UTF-8. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22544412/1639625)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Python re.search adding spaces to my string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542989/why-is-python-re-search-adding-spaces-to-my-string)

Comment: I tried this and it still comes up with the spaces but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but I run into the same problem. It was not an encoding error but a mismatch between the numbers of columns in my data and the number of entries in "header". It seems that the error also occurs when the table has only a single column.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like an encoding issue with `UTF-16`.  When a `UTF-16` file is interpreted as `UTF-8` (or a couple others) the resulting text has a null byte (`\x00`) in between the normal bytes, which ends up looking like everything has been separated by spaces.

Check out [tobias_k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22544412/208880) for a good method of dealing with it.

Comment: You have 14k+ rep, why write a link-only answer - specially one that replicates the same information from an older comment? If you think the other answer will apply to this question just mark it as a dupe.

Comment: @PauloScardine: Thanks for the nudge, I fleshed out my answer a bit more.  Oh, and just because the same answer can solve two different questions doesn't mean the questions were duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure we just want to make SO a better place. Regarding dupes you are right, just because two questions have the same answer it doesn't automatically make them duplicates. On the other side, just because two questions are worded differently doesn't mean they can't be dupes. For me the razor test is if the question adds significant value to stackoverflow, and IMHO this one doesn't - It is exactly the same problem from the other question. I guess we agree to  disagree.